# Host IIS applications form class libraries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm currently building an MVC webapp that is being hosted through IIS, and have been running into a big issue for a while now. The crux of this problem is that I have a collection of MVC projects that all need to be accessible under the same site. Normally this would be simple if each of these projects built as an exe and were converted to applications through IIS; however, each of these projects need to be class libraries. Is there a way this can work?

Comment: _"Normally this would be simple if each of these projects built as an exe and were converted to applications through IIS;"_ - what do you mean by this? Do you mean using FastCGI? (because IIS doesn't run EXEs like that, unless you're referring to how ASP.NET Core has stub entrypoint `.exe` files?)

Comment: Also, are you aware of IIS's concept of _Application Scopes_?

Comment: Like the other comment said, "Normally this would be simple if each of these projects built as an exe and were converted to applications through IIS" is not normal. The "applications" on IIS are different from "desktop applications" (which probably was the "exe" you were referring to), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis If you do want to keep multiple MVC projects but host them like a single web site, then you can configure them as separate sites and use a reverse proxy in front.

Comment: This seems like a bad try, if you want, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in circumstances like this is to create a simple `Host` Web Project that references everything else that is required.

You can then put all your Controllers, etc. in normal libraries. I've just done this on a (yes, currently-out-of-support) .NET 3.1 Core Web Project. The `Host` project references various normal libraries that contain my Controllers, DTOs etc.

The `Host` project only contains the `Program` and `Startup` classes. `Startup` then configures everything by pulling in services etc.